# ng-repeat: Ignore multiple time insertion of same angular template by directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I googled my problem but could not get a solution. I hope now I will definitely get the one.

I am making a directive in angular JS. for making a clickable link on repeatable text .

Lets say, I have some vouchers which i want to show using a ng-repeat and I want to make a directive which opens a modal with details of all the transactions under it.

My problem is, the ng-repeat is inserting the modal template in every loop which I think is making the DOM slow.

Directive:

```
.directive('viewVoucher', function($rootScope, CommonFunctionService, Server, $state, TplBaseUrl) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        voucherNumber:'@',
        voucherDate:'@',            
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    },
    templateUrl: TplBaseUrl()+'commonTpl/voucherViewModal.php',
    controller: function($scope, $element) {
        $scope.title = "Angularjs Bootstrap Modal Directive Example";
        $scope.showModal1 = false;

        $scope.hide = function(){
            $scope.showModal1 = false;
        }

        $scope.modalOneShown = function(){
            //console.log('model one shown');
            var params = {
            };
            Server.getInstance({apiName: 'someAPI'})
                .request('functionName',params,function(data) {
                if(CommonFunctionService.handleResponse(data)) {
                    $scope.voucherDetails = data.response; 
                } 
            });
        }

        $scope.modalOneHide = function(){
            //console.log('model one hidden');
        }
    },
};
})
```

If I use the above directive in ng-repeat, the modal template is getting inserted everytime
[image]

Comment: If possible then extract modal 'div' from directive and place it on a page and pass required parameters (ex: voucher number) to modal div by modifying 'ng-click="showmodal1"' and fetch data accordingly before showing modal

Comment: Are you using [UI-Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)?

Comment: @Protozoid, No i am not using the UI Bootstrap